# How to change geometry and font of Terminal on macOS?

Tags: terminal, macos

We can start `xterm` with specific size and font dynamically with

```
xterm -geometry ... -font ...
```

How can we do the same for Terminal on macOS?

Comment: Do you want a permanent Preferences setting, or a one-time special?

Comment: @AntonSherwood I know how to change in Preferences. I'd like to know if it's possible to set on the fly.

Comment: You'd do that with AppleScript, e.g., [this example](https://www.labnol.org/software/resize-mac-windows-to-specific-size/28345/).  There's an [Apple-specific](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) forum which would give more useful answers.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check try to use AppleScript, and see help at Apple-specific forum.